# "When" clause in second conditional

Tags: conditionals, when

I would like to ask you for clarification, if the usage of the *when* clause is correct in the second conditional.

In one book I found the sentence:

> *When the factory came online in 1990, he would control the best factory in the world.*

The first part of the sentence - *When the factory came online in 1990* - never happened.

Is the *when* clause correctly used instead of an *if* clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the context, it seems to me that this sentence is more an example of reported thought than the conditional. I assume that the author of the book was writing about the time before 1990, when the manufacturer had a firm plan for his factory to go online in that year.

The manufacturer's thinking, pre-1990, was:

> When the factory comes online in 1990, I will control the best factory
>   in the world.

This thinking was backshifted in its reporting by the author to:

> When the factory came online in 1990, he would control the best
>   factory in the world.

A dependent clause starting with *if* rather than  *when* is also possible. But it would convey a doubt about the realisation of the plan, which the manufacturer presumably did not have.

Comment: Or think of it as relative to somebody's belief at the time. For instance, in a novel set entirely in 1985, where the third-person narrative describes a character's thought process: ***He knew that*** *when the factory came online in 1990, he would control the best factory in the world.*